# Rearranging the rows/index in a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['John', 'Boby', 'Mina', 'Peter', 'Nicky','Teena'],
      'B': ['John', 'Boby', 'Mina', 'Peter', 'Nicky','Teena'],
      'C': [27, 23, 21, 23, 24,20]})
   
df
```

I created a pivot table using following code.

```
a=df.pivot_table(index="A", columns="B", values="C")
a
```

I need `Nicky` in the first row of pivot table. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reindex` on your columns just with the wanted columns first:

```
first = ['Nicky']
order = first+list(a.index.difference(first))

a.reindex(order)
```

Output:

```
B      Boby  John  Mina  Nicky  Peter  Teena
A                                           
Nicky   NaN   NaN   NaN   24.0    NaN    NaN
Boby   23.0   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
John    NaN  27.0   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
Mina    NaN   NaN  21.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
Peter   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   23.0    NaN
Teena   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN   20.0
```

If you want both Index and columns:

```
first = ['Nicky']
order = first+list(a.index.union(a.columns).difference(first))
a.reindex(index=order, columns=order)
```

Output:

```
B      Nicky  Boby  John  Mina  Peter  Teena
A                                           
Nicky   24.0   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
Boby     NaN  23.0   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
John     NaN   NaN  27.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
Mina     NaN   NaN   NaN  21.0    NaN    NaN
Peter    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   23.0    NaN
Teena    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   20.0
```

##### `reindex` vs `loc`

If you use this code on arbitrary input, Nick might be missing. In such case `loc` will raise an error as the key is not found. `reindex` will just create the missing indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iloc`:

```
order = [3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
a.iloc[order, order]
```

Output:

```
B      Nicky  Boby  John  Mina  Peter  Teena
A                                           
Nicky   24.0   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
Boby     NaN  23.0   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
John     NaN   NaN  27.0   NaN    NaN    NaN
Mina     NaN   NaN   NaN  21.0    NaN    NaN
Peter    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   23.0    NaN
Teena    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   20.0
```